# Verificar se existe conexão a internet Jquery

Tags: jquery

Alguém conhece um boa função ou um boa maneira de verificar se existe conexão a internet antes de efectuar um pedido ajax?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

É possível, tente:

```
var online = navigator.onLine; // true ou false, (há, não há conexão à internet)
if(online) {
    // efetuar pedido ajax
}
```

Para testar, crie um ficheiro no seu computador, ex: online.html e lá escreva:

```
<script>
    var online = navigator.onLine;
    alert(online);
</script>
```

Abra-o no navegador e desligue/ligue a conexão para testar