# Verificação em tempo real do estado da conexão com JS

Tags: javascript, http-request

Estou tentando realizar uma verificação em tempo real do estado de conexão com à internet usando JS, segue abaixo o meu código:

```
var checkConexao = window.setInterval(function() {

    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        //Oculta a modal informativa.
        $('#checkStatusConexao').fadeOut(1000);
    } else {
        //Exibe a modal informando que não há conexão com à internet.
        $('#checkStatusConexao').fadeIn('slow');
    }

}, 50);
```

Quando eu dou um alert no "readyState" ele sempre mostra como "undefined", mas quando eu deixo esse trecho assim:

```
if (this.readyState = 4 && this.status == 200) {
```

Ele funciona, mas sempre exibe a modal informando que não há internet, mesmo quando há conexão.

Desde já agradeço qualquer ajuda!

Comment: Vai bem mais além do que isso @Julio henrique.

Comment: Explique em sua pergunta o que vai além para nós entendermos melhor sua dúvida.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Já existe uma solução para essa pergunta [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/141851/verificar-se-existe-conex%C3%A3o-a-internet-jquery).
De uma olhada e veja se é o que você precisa.

Comment: Pois é @Jorge, obrigado pela sua ajuda, mas já até uso o "navigator.onLine", o problema é que ele só verifica se a conexão existe, mas não me diz se tem internet ativa nela ou não (Se há resposta do servidor à requisição http)

Comment: @WandersonBorges, achei [esse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189430/detect-the-internet-connection-is-offline) link , da uma olhada ai, pode te ajudar. Também tem algumas sugestões [aqui](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jquery-br/ChiddULJGOA).

Answer (score 0):

Bom, agradeço ao @Jorge, pois um dos links que ele me indicou me levou a outro link que me deu uma luz para criar uma solução caseira (hack) e resolver o problema...rsrs

Segue abaixo o código pronto (todo o código comentado):

```
<script>
//Aqui é feita a verificação de conexão com o "navigator.onLine" à cada 50 milisegundos.
var checkConexao = window.setInterval(function() {

    if (navigator.onLine) {
        //Aqui você está conectado, e oculta a modal informativa.
        $('#checkConexao').fadeOut(1000);
    } else {
        //Aqui você está desconectado, e exibe a modal informativa.
        $('#checkConexao').fadeIn('slow');
    }

}, 50);



//Aqui é carregada dentro de uma div vazia uma imagem da internet de 1px por 1px, de 20 em 20 segundos à fim de testar a conectividade com a internet na conexão atual.
var checkConexao = window.setInterval(function() {

    //A função "online" é ativada se a imagem for carregada corretamente (onload).
    //A função "offline" é ativada se houver erro no carregamento da imagem (onerror).
    document.getElementById("testeDeConexao").innerHTML = "<img id='imgCheckConexao' src='http://www.seusite.com.br/images/checkConexao.png' onload='online()' onerror='offline()' style='display: none;'>";

}, 20000);



function online() {
    //Aqui é feita a remoção da imagem carregada para poder carregá-la novamente do zero, e continuar com o ciclo.
    $('#imgCheckConexao').remove();

    //Aqui você tem acesso à internet na conexão atual, e oculta a modal informativa.
    $('#checkStatusConexao').fadeOut(1000);
}
function offline() {
    //Aqui é feita a remoção da imagem carregada para poder carregá-la novamente do zero, e continuar com o ciclo.
    $('#imgCheckConexao').remove();

    //Aqui você não tem acesso à internet na conexão atual, e exibe a modal informativa.
    $('#checkStatusConexao').fadeIn('slow');
}
```

Modais informativas (Sem estilização):

```
<div onclick="window.location.reload()" id="checkConexao" style="display: none;">
<center><img src="desconectado.png" alt="Será exibida se não estiver conectado à nenhuma rede" ></center>
```

```
<div onclick="window.location.reload()" id="checkStatusConexao" style="display: none;">
<center><img src="sem-internet.png" alt="Será exibida se não tiver acesso à internet na conexão atual"></center>
```